# How to prevent http call in Angular 2 when using observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Several examples demonstrate how to use observables to hook up a control to show data fetched from a http backend, such as this one: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Can you prevent that http call in certain situations? For example in the mentioned post there is an autocomplete field - is there a way to prevent the http call in case the user clears the field?

I have tried modifying the switchMap function with for example:

```
if(term.length < 1) {
   return Observable.empty();
}
else { // call the http service...
```

and it does prevent the call, but leaves the previous results at the control.

Comment: You are close. `Observable.empty` creates and `Observable` that never fires. You need one that fires with an empty array to clear the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I'm on mobile but something like `filter(term => term.length > 0)` should do the trick.

**UPDATE after comment**

There are probably more elegant ways of handling this but how about this?

```
this.items = this.term.valueChanges
             .debounceTime(400)
             .distinctUntilChanged()
             .switchMap(term => term.length > 0 
               ? this.wikipediaService.search(term) 
               : Observable.of([]));
```

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3p9eqiPAcqjBIEdLNkUG?p=preview

Comment: This does prevent the call, but it doesn't erase the existing list.

Comment: awesome solution! say I need a full function instead of one line =>, how do I return the original observable to be subscribed to? see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvt03jo6ndsw30u/Screenshot%202016-08-12%2013.46.45.png?dl=0