# Observables and minimum length on input in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am following some of the tutorials on Angular 2 and trying to put together a simple Typeahead component. It's working, but I would like to add the option of not hitting the server until a minimum length string has been typed. I am able to do this (sort of) by adding a filter into the flow, but I would like the typeahead to clear when I backspace back below the minimum (or delete the text from the input). Currently if I type in the minimum length and backspace the results stay.

I can add *ngIf and form validation to the `table` but this feel hack-y and I think I  but should be able to send an empty array to the template somehow instead. But I can't find anything that works.

This is the stripped down version of what I have:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'typeahead',
    template: `
        <div>
            <input
                required
                type="text"
                placeholder="Person"
                #person [ngFormControl]="searchText">
        </div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#person of people | async">
                <td> {{person.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TypeAhead {
    searchText = new Control(); 
    people: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(db:DBService){
        this.people = this.searchText.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(200)
        .filter((val:string) => (val.length > 1))
        .switchMap((val:string) => db.searchNodes("Person", val))   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Andreas.  `observable`,  `input` and `minimum` are also tags so perhaps I should rename question "length" — certainly more succinct.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, when SO question titles appear in google search results, it is quite useful to see "Angular 2" in the question.  Especially since there is an Angular "1".

Comment: @MarkRajcok please read the linked thread on meta. there is a difference in style matters of how to include such organic things. tagging with ` - tag` or `tag: ` should be avoided as this is considered somewhat bad practice, and a more natural wording should be done in such cases.

Comment: @MarkRajcok additionnaly, tags are included in search results by Google anyway...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, sometimes I see the first tag appear in search results, but it doesn't seem (to me) to be consistent.  And if an Angular 2 question is tagged with both "angularjs" and "angular2" tags, it will likely appear as "angularjs - question title here".  Thanks for clarifying about not using `tag:` in the question title, and the more natural wording.

Comment: @MarkRajcok very good point - yet, it should be resolved by prioritizing the order (ie if you prefix your question with a tag, why not let it be the first real tag instead?) thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a clean working solution based on:
[How to prevent http call in Angular 2 when using observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670868/how-to-prevent-http-call-in-angular-2-when-using-observables/34676605#34676605)

```
constructor(db:DBService){
    this.people = this.searchText.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(200)
    .switchMap((val:string) =>  val.length > 1
        ? db.searchNodes("Person", val))
        : Observable.of([]))   
}
```

In order to use `Observable.of` you'll need to import `import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to make two different events happen.

One is for calling your searchNodes (only happens when you have two or more characters). The other is for clearing the result once you backspace.

When you think of it this way (which is the simplest and thus the best?) the solution becomes easy.

**TL;DR**
Just add a second listener to your `this.searchText.valueChanges` that checks for backspace - and clear the result.

Note: If `.valueChanges` does not include the keypressed, then I'm pretty sure there is another event that captures they keys pressed. Lastly, you could (i wouldn't recommend) keep a log of search results and then act when the length of that searchString is reduced.

Comment: Hi @Per, I appreciate the help. The` people` that the template is watching is an `observable` coming from `http`. I'm not quite sure what I need to set `people` to in order to clear the value. Setting it to `[]` doesn't work and of course the compiler complains because it's not the right type. I thought maybe I could send my own Observable, but that just isn't working either. Any idea?